# Recommend based on search key word

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a `input query` table in the following:

```
    query
0  orange
1   apple
2    meat
```

which I want to make against the `user query` table as following

```
   user       query
0    a1      orange
1    a1  strawberry
2    a1        pear
3    a2      orange
4    a2  strawberry
5    a2       lemon
6    a3      orange
7    a3      banana
8    a6        meat
9    a7        beer
10   a8       juice
```

Given a query in `input query`, I want to match it to query by other user in `user query` table, and return the top 3 ranked by total number of counts.

For example,
`orange` in `input query`, it matches user `a1`,`a2`,`a3` in `user query` where all have queried `orange`, other items they have query are `strawberry` (count of 2), `pear`, `lemon`, `banana` (count of 1).

The answer will be `strawberry` （since it has max count), `pear`, `lemon` (since we only return top 3).

Similar reasoning for `apple` (no user query therefore output 'nothing') and `meat` query.

So the final `output table` is

```
    query   recommend
0  orange  strawberry
1  orange        pear
2  orange       lemon
3   apple     nothing
4    meat     nothing
```

What's the efficient way to do that given `user query` have 1 million rows?

here's the code for `input query`, `user query` and `output table`

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame( {'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'apple', 2: 'meat'}} )
df_user = pd.DataFrame( {'user': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a1', 3: 'a2', 4: 'a2', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a3', 7: 'a3', 8: 'a6', 9: 'a7', 10: 'a8'}, 'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'strawberry', 2: 'pear', 3: 'orange', 4: 'strawberry', 5: 'lemon', 6: 'orange', 7: 'banana', 8: 'meat', 9: 'beer', 10: 'juice'}} )
df_output = pd.DataFrame( {'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'orange', 2: 'orange', 3: 'apple', 4: 'meat'}, 'recommend': {0: 'strawberry', 1: 'pear', 2: 'lemon', 3: 'nothing', 4: 'nothing'}} )
```

Comment: There is a really fast and efficient way to do this with matrices, sorry I cant be much help past that.

Comment: I don't understand why meat -> beer, meat -> juice appear in the output table. I thought it should be meat -> nothing.

Comment: @quasi-human Exactly, I have modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on a memory resource you have, choose either of the following solutions.

### Code:

#### # Preparation:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframes
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'apple', 2: 'meat'}})
df_user = pd.DataFrame({'user': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a1', 3: 'a2', 4: 'a2', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a3', 7: 'a3', 8: 'a6', 9: 'a7', 10: 'a8'}, 'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'strawberry', 2: 'pear', 3: 'orange', 4: 'strawberry', 5: 'lemon', 6: 'orange', 7: 'banana', 8: 'meat', 9: 'beer', 10: 'juice'}})

# Define how many recommended items you need for each query
n_top = 3

# Exclude unnecessary rows for caluculation
dfu = df_user.drop_duplicates()
queries = df_input['query']
users = dfu.loc[dfu['query'].isin(queries), 'user'].drop_duplicates()
mask_q = dfu['query'].isin(queries)
mask_u = dfu['user'].isin(users)
df1 = dfu[mask_u&mask_q].set_index('user')
df2 = dfu[mask_u].set_index('user')
```

#### # Solution 1:

If you have a large memory resource, try the following code.

```py
# Carry out the basket analysis
df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')
df = df[df.query_x!=df.query_y].reset_index()
df = df.groupby(['query_x', 'query_y'], as_index=False).count()
df = df.sort_values('user', ascending=False).groupby('query_x').head(n_top)
df = df.drop('user', axis=1).rename(columns={'query_x': 'query', 'query_y': 'recommend'})
df = df_input.merge(df, how='left', on='query').fillna('nothing')
```

#### # Solution 2:

If you have a limitation of a memory resource, try the following code. It takes much longer than the solution 1, but you can complete the calculation almost certainly.

```py
# Carry out the basket analysis
df = pd.DataFrame()
for _, df_q1 in df1.groupby('query'):
    _df = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, df_q2 in df2.groupby('query'):
        df_q1q2 = df_q1.join(df_q2, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')
        df_q1q2 = df_q1q2.reset_index().groupby(['query_x', 'query_y'], as_index=False).count()
        _df = _df.append(df_q1q2)
    _df = _df[_df.query_x!=_df.query_y]
    _df = _df.sort_values('user', ascending=False).groupby('query_x').head(n_top)
    df = df.append(_df)
df = df.drop('user', axis=1).rename(columns={'query_x': 'query', 'query_y': 'recommend'})
df = df_input.merge(df, how='left', on='query').fillna('nothing')
```

### Output of both solution 1 and 2:

|  | query | recommend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | orange | strawberry |
| 1 | orange | banana |
| 2 | orange | lemon |
| 3 | apple | nothing |
| 4 | meat | nothing |

Comment: beautiful solution

Comment: Thanks. I imporved the performance of the calculation. Please check the updated answer.